# How do I file a criminal complaint in Germany?

Tags: criminal-law, germany

How can I lay a criminal complaint before the governmental prosecutor according to § 158 (Strafanzeige; Strafantrag) StPO?  Need I follow a particular format?  where do I send it?  Can I submit an anonymous complaint, and if so does the prosecutor take those seriously?

I read the following tweet from Henry B. Poquelin*: "Fakt bleibt, man muss Positionen und Personal der Rechtspopulisten attackieren,weil sie gestrig,intolerant, rechtsaußen und gefährlich sind!" I hate AfD and its politics, but still I don't like the call for criminal violence against people and property. I thought of a prosecution based on §111 and §130 StGB.

Well, I will certainly not prosecute him, but I still would like to write a correct letter to the government lawyers and knowing how to send it anonymously to them.

*I'm using a pseudonym here to avoid listing the name of the famous SPD politician. I don't want to start a witch hunt on him.

Comment: I don't understand your question completely, but there are no formal requirements for a criminal complaint. If you send it somehow to any police, public prosecutor or local court they are having to deal with it. Just don't go in person because in that case they need to identify you. According to Google somebody already filed a criminal complaint, btw.

Comment: I don't see any call for criminal violence here.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that online, this website will help you with that:
http://www.online-strafanzeige.de/

Also, just go to the police... They must accept your complaint and will check it. Also they can tell you wether it is likely that the complaint will lead to a lawsuit or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a violation of the cited law here, since "attack" doesn't necessary imply violence. It could also mean confronting them in the political discourse. And we're far away from § 130 StGB here. You have to apply these laws restrictively to not overly restrict the right of free speech. 
So your complaint will most probably lead nowhere.